# Is the field BusID necessary in XF86Config?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, xorg

I am using a cluster of machines running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS which are supposed to be homogeneous, but apparently they are not. In particular, I am configuring the X server on these machines, and I pushed a /etc/X11/XF86Config that includes the following section:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection
```

The problem is that the BusID of the graphic card is PCI:5:0:0 for some machines, and PCI:3:0:0 for others. Is there a way that the X server automatically detects the appropriate Device (based on the name for instance)?

Thanks,

Comment: XF86Config?  Surely you mean xorg.conf - Ubuntu is far too new for XFree86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is optional according to the documentation:

BusID "bus-id"
  ... This field is usually optional in single-head configurations when using the primary graphics card.  In multi-head configurations, or when using a secondary graphics card in a single-head configuration, this entry is mandatory ...

That text can be found here (search for "BusID" in the resulting page to get to the relevant "BusID" section that is roughly half way down the page):  http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.2/XF86Config.5.html

Comment: Ok, but isn't there another way of selecting the secondary graphics card over the primary one? Apparently not according to the doc... So I therefore need to enter manually the BusID for each of the nodes.

Comment: Unless you have a way of programmatically finding out the bus-id and substituting it.

Comment: Yes, but this is always feasible :P The only question is: what will consume the least of my time?